# How to change the color of menu control in javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

in an another question I find this possibilty with css

```css
.menu .label
{
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

but it doesn't work with the `setStyle` method 
`menu.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");`

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question? To change the text color of a menu in JavaFX, use an external stylesheet with the CSS code you've shown.

Comment: I mean what's the difference between applying  -fx-text-fill: black; from a CSS stylesheet or by using setStyle method, why it doesn't work with them both?

Comment: Because in the stylesheet you are applying the rule to the label that is contained in the menu, but in the Java code you are applying the rule to the menu. Menus don't have a `-fx-text-fill` CSS property. (As already explained in @rli's answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS applies the style to each Label below a Menu.

Whereas `menu.setStyle(...)` will apply only to the menu itself. And the menu itself does not have a `-fx-text-fill` property.

If you change your CSS to:

```
.menu
{
     -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
```

then it will be the same as your code ... and also stop to show the menu in color.

Menus don't support setting their font color like this. The CSS solution relies on an implementation detail.

If you don't want to do that you must use `menu.setGraphic(...)` to set a node, e.g:

```
    Menu menuFile = new Menu("");  
    Label t = new Label("File");
    t.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: blue;");
    menuFile.setGraphic(t);
```